# How to add a custom exception on symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony(using version 2.2) and trying to add a custom exception listener.
I have read the following links but cannot get it to work.

- [Overriding Symfony 2 exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336665/overriding-symfony-2-exceptions)
- [Symfony2 Custom Error Exception Listener - Rendering templates or passing to a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256252/symfony2-custom-error-exception-listener-rendering-templates-or-passing-to-a-c)

What I'm trying to do is to create a custom Error Exception Listener and use it from my controllers and services like this,

```
throw new jsonErrorException('invalid_params');
```

to display json twig template like this.(I'm developing a background program for my native smartphone applications)

```
{"status": "error", "message": "invalid_params"}
```

I have registered my CustomEventListener to my src/My/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml and created a custom exception class as shown on following link([Overriding Symfony 2 exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336665/overriding-symfony-2-exceptions)) but I get the error

```
symfony exceptions must be valid objects derived from the exception base class
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create custom exception the "symfony way" let's look at how exception or created in symfony:

first create your customExceptionInterface

```
namespace My\SymfonyBundle\Exception;
/**
 * Interface for my bundle exceptions.
 */
interface MySymfonyBundleExceptionInterface
{
}
```

And create your `jsonErrorException`

```
namespace My\SymfonyBundle\Exception;

class HttpException extends \Exception implements MySymfonyBundleExceptionInterface
{
}
```

Don't hesitate to browse [symfony's exceptions](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception) code examples on github

Comment: Thanks for helping!
I'm almost there but I can't find out how to render a custom twig template. (I don't need to use twig, since it's not a long text, but I prefer using it)

Comment: [twig configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-exception-controller) to stop rendering the default twig template.

Comment: Thank you for the help!
I figured out a way to render specific twig template by editing the Exception Listener.
[link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-exception-controller) you gave me also helped!

Answer (score 6):

I recently implemented a custom exception in my Symfony2 service in the following manner:

`MemberAlreadyExistsException.php`

```
<?php

namespace Aalaap\MyAppBundle\Services\Membership;

class MemberAlreadyExistsException extends \Exception
{

}
```

`Subscriber.php`

```
<?php

namespace Aalaap\MyAppBundle\Services\Membership;
...
throw new MemberAlreadyExistsException(
    'The member you are trying to subscribe already'
    . ' exists in this list.'
);
...
```

Comment: Quick and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the Exception class, or at least the Symfony's inner exception class

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add `\` and the global scope worked in a Symfony service

```
namespace App\CoreBundle\Service;

class CurrencyExchange
{
    const RATES_XML = 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?849b4b329863b2d60bfd0de486e423c9';

    const RATES_XML_PATH = 'uploads/ecb_currencies.xml';

    /** @var array $rates */
    private $rates;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!is_file(self::RATES_XML_PATH)) {
            throw new \Exception('XML '.self::RATES_XML_PATH.' does not exists.');
        }

        if (1 > filesize(self::RATES_XML_PATH)) {
            throw new \Exception('XML '.self::RATES_XML_PATH.' is empty.');
        }
```