# Create Json Exception with Symfony

Tags: json, symfony

I want create a JSON Exception with Symfny in a controller. I can create a HTML exception with

```
 try {
     // code here
 } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
       throw $this->createNotFoundException($e->getMessage());
 }
```

But it returns an HTML exception.

I try:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException($e->getMessage())->setHeaders(['Content-Type'=>'application/json']);
```

But don't works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom exception behavior in symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787482/custom-exception-behavior-in-symfony2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099962/how-to-add-a-custom-exception-on-symfony2